# NSubstitute - faking a virtual method that calls another virtual method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual bool A()
    {
        return 5 < B();
    }

    protected virtual int B()
    {
        return new Random.Next(1, 10);
    }
}
```

When writing tests for `MyClass` it would be handy to be able to do the following:

```
[Fact]
public void Blabla()
{
    var o = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();
    o.A().Returns(true);

    Assert.True(o.DoSomethingElse());
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I get a runtime exception:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException
>
> Can not return value of type Boolean for MyClass.A (expected type int).

Is there a way to get around this, or do I have to create a concrete test double class overriding `A`?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by modifying the test-code as follows:

```
var o = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();
o.When(x => x.A()).DoNotCallBase();
o.A().Returns(true);

Assert.True(o.DoSomethingElse());
```

This prevents the fake from calling the actual implementation in the following `Returns()` call.